# How to reference arrays in other methods for mathematical operations?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I've been trying to implement a program that can take the preassigned values from a 2d array and calculate individual elements within it into 1d arrays, which are then displayed separately from the 2d array.

Here's an example:

```
      public int[,] GetTemperatures()
        {
            int[,] dailyTemperature =
            {
                {38, 40, 42, 34},
                {55, 41, 40, 30},
                {28, 39, 21, 60},
                {61, 52, 43, 42},
                {35, 36, 30, 29},
                {24, 33, 37, 40}
            };

            Console.Write(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < dailyTemperature.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < dailyTemperature.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i].Substring(0, dailyTemperature[i].Length - 1) + " "); 

                for (int j = 0; j < dailyTemperature.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i, j] + "    "); 
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return dailyTemperature;
}
```

```
      public int[] GetTemperatureSum(int [,] dailyTemperature)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < temperatureSum.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                int[] temperatureSum = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                temperatureSum[0] = dailyTemperature[0, 0] + dailyTemperature[0, 1] + dailyTemperature[0, 2] + dailyTemperature[0, 3];
                temperatureSum[1] = dailyTemperature[1, 0] + dailyTemperature[1, 1] + dailyTemperature[1, 2] + dailyTemperature[1, 3];
                temperatureSum[2] = dailyTemperature[2, 0] + dailyTemperature[2, 1] + dailyTemperature[2, 2] + dailyTemperature[2, 3];
                temperatureSum[3] = dailyTemperature[3, 0] + dailyTemperature[3, 1] + dailyTemperature[3, 2] + dailyTemperature[3, 3];
                temperatureSum[4] = dailyTemperature[4, 0] + dailyTemperature[4, 1] + dailyTemperature[4, 2] + dailyTemperature[4, 3];
                temperatureSum[5] = dailyTemperature[5, 0] + dailyTemperature[5, 1] + dailyTemperature[5, 2] + dailyTemperature[5, 3];

                Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i] + " ");

            }
            return dailyTemperature;
        }
```

The former is the first method from which I am pulling the values. I'm trying to add the sums from each of the 6 rows, resulting in a horizontal 1d array with six elements. The latter is the second method, in which I am adding the sums of these temperatures in each of the rows.
Whenever I run this, however, I get errors along the lines of "The method or operation is not implemented" and "the method is not instantiated." I'd love it if someone could help me understand what is going on and how to do this.

Comment: That `GetTemperatureSum` makes no sense at all. You pass in a 2D `int` array and you return that same array without having made any changes to it, even though the method says that it returns a 1D array. Also, on each iteration of the loop, you create a populated array, discard each element as you replace them with new values, then discard the whole array. Put down your keyboard and pick up a pen and paper. Write down the actual logic you want to implement. Formalise that logic into an algorithm. Test the algorithm manually. Finally, write code the explicitly implements that algorithm.

Comment: I didn't initially have the 2D int array in, but I put it in as final attempt to call in the values from the 2D array so that I could collect their sums. With regards to the values in the second array, they are just supposed to be placeholders which I put in as a way to mimic some examples that I saw. I do not know how to formalize this logic into an algorithm or how to write down this logic any more clearly than I already have, which is why I've decided to ask a question.